# Overflow screen custom navbar(bootstrap) without horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a custom `navbar`(bootstrap) on my page.

```
<nav class='navbar fixed-top navCustom '>

    <div class='navComp'>

        <input class='dateStyle' id='dateChart' type='date' value='" . $now . "'/>

        <button id='refreshBtn' class='refreshStyle' type='button' name='refresh'>Refresh</button>

        <form style='display:inline' method='post' action=''>
            <button id='logout' class='logoutStyle' type='submit' name='logout'>Log Out</button>
        </form>

    </div>

</nav>
```

Here is css of `navCustom` and `navComp`:

```
@media (min-width:600px) {

    .navCustom{
        justify-content: center !important;
    }

}

.navCustom{
    margin-top: -1px;
    height: 33px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.navComp{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #dadada;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    box-shadow:0 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

My problem is when the size of browser is thin.

[image: 1]

The `navbar` overflow on the right margin of browser, but scrollbar don't appears.

The scrollbar appears only when `divs` with text `Test` overflow on the right margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out.

`.fixed-top` from Bootstrap has `position: fixed` which is the reason why scroll bar is not triggered by my element.

I fixed it by added `position: sticky !important;` into my `.navCustom`

That made me to change a little bit my css and structure, but at least I had obtained what I wanted.